# How can I place element to position with Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, layout

I want to draw rectangle to position what I get from startPoint, but now it places my rectangle to middle of PictureCanvas, when I want to put it in startPoint position

```
private void DragSelectComponent_SelectionEnd(DragSelectEventArgs e)
{
    Output.Text = "Start: " + e.StartPoint.ToString() + "     End: " + e.EndPoint.ToString() + "\n(" + e.EventType + ")\n";
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle() { Width = e.EndPoint.X - e.StartPoint.X, Height = e.EndPoint.Y - e.StartPoint.Y, Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple) };
    PictureCanvas.Children.Add(rectangle);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:-

```
 Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle() { Width = e.EndPoint.X - e.StartPoint.X, Height = e.EndPoint.Y - e.StartPoint.Y, Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple) };
 Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, e.StartPoint.X);
 Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, e.StartPoint.Y);
 PictureCanvas.Children.Add(rectangle);
```

Comment: It didn't work, for some reason my rectangle is still in the middle of PictureCanvas

Comment: You are sure that "PictureCanvas" is actually a Canvas? Are you sure that the rectangle in the event args __doesn't__ describe a rectangle in the middle of the Canvas?

Comment: PictureCanvas is Grid element. should it be Canvas element?

Comment: <Grid Width="500" x:Name="PictureCanvas" Height="500" Background="Orange" Grid.Column="1"></Grid>

Comment: The Canvas Left and Top properties only make sense when you place the item on a Canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
rectangle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, p.X);
rectangle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, p.Y);
```